# ORA-01403: no data found in automatic row fetch

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an APEX page with a button that opens a modal dialog page for creating new record. When a link clicked on an interactive report, the record clicked is loaded on the modal dialog page. On that page I can either edit existing record or create a new one. When editing current record, a primary key is passed in and when creating a new records, it is not.

On the modal dialog page I have an automatic row fetch. I started getting `ORA-01403: no data found` error because the row fetch does not return any records (obviously, because no record exists when the "create new" button is clicked). My question is how can I avoid getting the error in the fetch when primary key is null.

Comment: A normal Automatic Row Fetch process will not raise "no data found" if the PK item is null. Somehow your page is getting passed an ID value that doesn't exist in the table. You might need to set Clear Session in the link for the Create button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about modifying the process by setting its "Server side condition"? Its type would be `Item is NOT NULL`, and you'd set the primary key item as *the item*.